# what does temp2->next contain?

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, pointers, linked-list

This is a program trying to make a linked list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
char name[20];
int age;
int height;
node* next; // Pointer to the next node
 };
 node* startPTR = NULL; // Start Pointer (root)
                   // This pointer permanantly points to the start of the list
                   // Initially there are no nodes

void addNode_AT_END(); // prototype for the function that 'adds nodes at the end'

int main() {
   do {
 addNode_AT_END();
     cout << "Add more ?";
     char ch;
     cin >> ch;
   } while( ch == 'y');
}

void addNode_AT_END() {
node *temp1;
node *temp2;
temp1 = new node;  // We declare space for a pointer item and assign a temporary pointer to it  
                   //*temp1 is the node that it points to
cout << "Enter the name : ";
cin >> temp1->name;
cout << endl << "Enter the age : ";
cin >> temp1->age;
cout << endl << "Enter height : ";
cin >> temp1->height;
temp1->next = NULL; // indicates that this node when inserted in the list will be the last node
  if( startPTR == NULL) {
    startPTR = temp1;  // In the empty list last node will be the first node
  }  else {
        temp2 = startPTR;
        while( temp2->next != NULL )
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1;
     }
```

}

From this *yet to be completed* program this is what i understand :

[image]

If the figure after the second call to the function `addNode_AT_END` is true, then what does `temp2->next` in the statement `while( temp2->next != NULL )` contain ?

Comment: There Is a homework tag you know ;-)

Comment: @Suhail Gupta startPTR is not pointing to temp1, it is pointing the starting node which is pointed by temp1. Hence your diagram needs correction.

Comment: @ EAGER_STUDENT Then what does `startPTR = temp1` mean ?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta  And startPTR is a pointer and how come in your diagram temp2 points to startPTR?

Comment: @ Nicolas Grebille For some situations i will like to introduce a `self satisfaction` tag

Comment: @Suhail Gupta It means that startPTR points to the node (say of address 2000) which is pointed by temp1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagrams are incorrect. start = temp2 does means that start and temp2 pointers both point to the same node. Your diagram shows the next field of the temp2 pointer holds the address of start . Also after doing `start->next = temp1` does not mean that if you get some new node value in `temp1` (in the next function call), the `start->next` will still keep pointing to the new value just allocated in `temp1`. It will hold the old value that was in before you overwrote it with the new one. `start->next = temp1` simply copies the value in `temp1`  ie. an address to the variable (pointer variable) the next component of the node pointed by start which is `start->next` . After that there is no connection between start and `temp1`.

In linked list context "temp1 ----> temp2" means the `next` field of the node whose address is stored in `temp1`, holds the address of the node with an address which was held or is held by `temp2` . Now after you change the value of the pointer variable `temp2` does not change the `next` field of the node held at address stored in `temp1`. `temp1->next` still contains the value which it stored before.

**The next links does not point to some variable name, that is, `start->next = temp` will not make `start` node's next node always pointing to the whatever node `temp1` contains, but it `start->next` will contain the address which `temp1` stored at the time of the assignment.**

note that by saying "start is pointing to temp1" means that the address

```
while (temp2->next != NULL)
  temp2 = temp2->next;
```

will break when `temp2->next = NULL` which means that `temp2` points to the last node of the list. At this point `temp2->next = temp1` links the newly allocated node after the node currently pointed by `temp2`. Which is simply adds the new node at the end.

```
  At the end of the above while loop

                                                              temp2
                                                                |
                                                                V

(start) ----> (n1) ----> (n2) ----> (n3) . . . (n(n-1)) ----> (nn) ----> NULL


   temp2->next = temp1    makes


                                                              temp2
                                                                |
                                                                V

(start) ----> (n1) ----> (n2) ----> (n3) . . . (n(n-1)) ----> (nn) ----> (temp1)--->NULL


 because temp2 holds the address of (nn) therefore linking the new node to the next node of the last node.
```

**UPDATE**

First time:

```
start = NULL
a new address is allocated and the address stored into temp1 pointer. Also temp->next = NULL
if condition becomes true and temp1 is assigned to start
start = temp1

List state


start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (NULL)
```

Second time:

```
a new node is allocated and the address of the new node is stored into `temp1`. Let this address be `addr2`. Now `temp1` contains the value `addr2`

start is NOT NULL, as start has addr1 in it from the last call.So the else part is true and we get the address of the start node `addr1` into temp2.

temp2 = start;

which means temp2 now points to `addr1`

while loop is encountered. The first iteration the condition `temp2->next != NULL` is FALSE. This is because `temp2` points to `addr1` and the next pointer field of `addr1` has NULL from the last time the function is called. Therefore the while loop terminates.

The next statement does `temp2->next = temp1` . `temp2` points to `addr1` address, and the address of the newly allocated node `addr2` contained in `temp1` is assigned into the next field of the node whose address is stored into `temp2`. Which actually assigns the address `addr2` to the next field of the node identified by the address `addr1`.


temp1 = addr2     after allocation

start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (NULL)      at begining
 ^
 |
 temp2


after temp2->next = temp1

start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)      at end
 ^
 |
 temp2
```

Third time:

```
temp1 = addr3      new node address allocated

start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)      at start
 ^
 |
 temp2


start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)      next iteration after temp2=temp2->next
                 ^                      
                 |
               temp2


we can see temp2->next = NULL and while condition is false. Note that temp2 contains itself the address addr2, and thus temp2->next is NOT addr2, it is NULL.

start = addr1;
 |
 V
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (NULL)      next iteration after temp2=temp2->next
                 ^                      
                 |
               temp2



After linking: temp2->next = temp1;

start = addr1;               temp1         the address addr3 (new node)
 |                             |          is stored in temp1. this address is assigned
 V                             V         to the next node of temp2, replacing NULL
(addr1) ----> (addr2) ----> (addr3) ----> (NULL)      
                 ^                      
                 |
               temp2
```

The pointers are the means to travel/traverse through the list. The starting address of the list is held in a pointer `start`. As the next field of each node points to the next node, if we get the `start` node, then by following the next fields sequentially we can visit each node. `temp1` and `temp2` are pointers with which the traversals are done, they act as temporary pointers, `temp1` is used to hold the newly allocated node, and `temp2` is used to travel through the list by following the `next` links till the last, when the last link is found (detected by the NULL pointer in the next field), the NULL link of this last node is replaced by the newly allocated node held by `temp1` . As now the node held by `temp1` is linked/added to the end of the list, `temp1` is reused to hold another new node.

Comment: @Code Monkey: only for the first iteration, after which the new node is linked after the head node, and from the next call the while loop will be entered.

Comment: @downvoter: a justification for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: after the second node is created how it is linked to the first node ?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: have a look at the edit. Your diagrams are incorrect. start = temp2 does means that start and temp2 pointers both point to the *same node*. Your diagram shows the next field of the `temp2` pointer holds the address of `start` .

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: some more edits, have a look. sorry for the messy diagrams.

Comment: in the third call how does iteration happen ? After the second call the first node knew the address of second node after referring `temp2->next=temp1`. But all that vanishes  during the third call. How is list joining after the 2nd call ?

Comment: Why do you think it vanishes after the second call?

Comment: read the text in bold in my answer. `temp2->next = temp1`  means that the address value **currently stored in** `temp1` is copied into the `next` field of the node with an address which is **currently stored in** `temp2`.  I will ask you to get a copy and a pen (phisical) and try tracing whats going on. once you link the nodes the node structure stays intact as they are held by the `next` field of each node.

Comment: @ phoxis thank you ! It did, And why you stressed on physical with the pen ? !

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: most of people open the image editor or the text editor when asked for scribbling something. The physical pen and paper is *still* the best way to draft ideas, understand things, and take notes, i believe that. I am very happy to know that you were able to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

It contains `NULL`, and that is because of this line:

```
temp1->next = NULL;
```

Every new node has `next`pointer which you make `NULL` by doing the above step, and the new node is appended at the end of the list, as a result of which, the end of the list is always`NULL`. The `while` loop is traversing to the end of the list, and `while(temp2->next != NULL)` sets the condition which says until `next` of `temp2` becomes `NULL`, do `temp2 = temp2->next`.

Comment: every time the value is set to null before,therefore the while loop should never execute ?!